# Get width of iOS today extension

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get the width value of my widget / today extension.

I can't use `self.view.frame.size.width` because it returns the whole screen width and not the actual widget width (on the iPad the width of the extension is not equal to the screen width).

What can I do to get the actual width of the widget?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

..............
Don't read self.view.frame in **viewDidLoad**.

frame = (0 0; 768 1024); // in viewDidLoad

You should read self.view.frame after **viewDidAppear**

after **viewDidAppear**, self.view.frame is right value for content.

frame = (0 0; 545 75.5); // in viewDidAppear

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `viewDidAppear`, I found that `viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator` is triggered automatically when the widget gets resized initially